# creating components by running array on Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component that is going to create a child component by running an array with arrays on each element. 
In each element I have the path of the image in a variable called logo, this way:

````
    ```jsx    
Premio : [
    {key:11, name:'EMPTY', premio:0, logo:ruta1, special:"EMPTY"},
    {key:12, name:'BONUS', premio:1, logo:ruta2, special:"BONUS"},
````

This is in my general condition that drives Redux, so far ok

My component has no problem in printing all the names of the prizes since I save all the list in a variable when necessary to show it later in the render:

````
    ```jsx
premioCopia = this.props.Premio
listadoDePremios = premioCopia.map(task => task.name)
````

My problem is when I want to show the images one after the other. I tried to do it with the map and using a child component that takes the route from the props (it works normally).
My child Prize:

````
    ```jsx
    class Premio extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
  return(  <img src={this.props.img} />)
    }
  }
````

I try to do it this way from father class, from a function in the return:

````
    ```jsx
arrayPremios(premioCopia){
  <div>
      {premioCopia.map((element, key) =>
          <Premio key={key} src={element.logo} />
      )}
  </div>
}
````

And give me compilation error:

I have also tried with

````
    ```jsx
arrayPremios(premioCopia){
premioCopia.forEach(function(logo) {
<Premio src={premioCopia.logo} />
}
)}
````

And nothing neither, :(

Answer (score 0):

When you say it gives a compile error, it would be good to know the error to help solve the issue. However, I did notice you are referencing the wrong prop

you pass `src` to the component, but try to access the source with key `img`

```
<Premio key={key} src={element.logo} />
```

so change in here to pull the correct prop

```
class Premio extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return
      <img src={this.props.src} />
  }
}
```

Aka, change this `<img src={this.props.img} />` to this `<img src={this.props.src} />`

---

#### Edit

you need to return from your function.

```
arrayPremios(premioCopia){
  return (
    <div>
      {premioCopia.map((element, key) =>
          <Premio key={key} src={element.logo} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks John.
Modified function to:

arrayPremios(premioCopia){
  <div> . (THIS IS LINE 21 )
      {premioCopia.map((element, key) =>
          <Premio key={key} src={element.logo} />
      )}
  </div>
}

and component "Premio" like you tell me. 
The error showed to me is:
Failed to compile:
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unuserd-expressiones at line 21 
At line 21 is where starts <div>

Comment: @Txarlye thanks for sharing the exception! edited my answer to help fix that problem :)

Comment: @Txarlye happy to help;! When you can if you could mark the answer as the correct answer it would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Because I'm new contributor i can mark but my action is not showing until my reputation grows, sorry. I hope soon i have enough and this shows. Thanks other time John !